# How to draw Gaussian Distribution curve

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-algorithm

I want to draw a Gaussian Distribution curve, i know 
p(x) = (1/σRoot(2π)) x exp (- (x-μ)2/2σ2),

i got the mean and standard deviation, but now i don't know how to proceed, how this bell-graph will be drawn, from where to get the co-ordinates, what's the use of above formula.
I searched a lot on internet and got nothing, every where it's given that how to draw it in excel or in matlab, but nowhere i found how those co-ordinates are got and how those curves are drawn.

if anyone can give me any idea on this it will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph is simply a set of points plotted on the plane. So basically what you do is pick a set of x-coordinates that you want to plot the curve on. Then plug those x values into your function `p(x)` to get the y-coordinates.

Lastly, plot the resultant points.

Most graphing software (like your standard graphing calculator) will automate all this functionality for you.